# Google Play services out of date. Requires 9683000 but found 9452230

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I've been testing my android app on a phone with Android 5.1.1 and everything's been working fine, but today I tested it on a tablet with Android 5.0.2 and I'm getting the following warning and the app won't run its service:

`GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9683000 but found 9452230`

Here's my gradle.build file, everything seems to be up to date. I've already checked the tablet for updates and there seem to be none.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "alpha"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix the problem, thank you!

**EDIT**

Here's the full logcat from the adb shell in case its any help:

```
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080ad0 (t=7 e=2768) (error -75)
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8454400
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{37623128 token=android.os.BinderProxy@149bad0e {alpha.MainActivity}} show : true
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@149bad0e time:8624348
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9683000 but found 9452230
```

Comment: update it on your device ?

Comment: Google Play Services? I've checked for updates but there are none.

Comment: well, there is indeed something to update.

Comment: Have you tried running all Platform and Plugin Updates in Android Studio? I had the same problem before updating my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If the tablet's Google Play Services is up-to-date, you may not have the latest SDK versions.

- Go to the SDK Manager and open the stand alone SDK Manager
- Update the Android SDK Tools, The Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Build-tools.

Hopefully the referenced libraries will be checked and you'll not encounter the issue after this.